# Best Approach to UI Development with Perl

Tags: php, perl, user-interface

There are several Perl scripts which are used daily in my team. The back end is an Oracle 11g database.

Perl scripts read data from the database and do business processing and then generate the reports/writes into database/or generate statements for internal purposes.

There are more than 20 Perl scripts are in place, and are expected to grow to max 50 as we are moving away from manual work to automated scripts.

All the Perl scripts are run manually from the command prompt or from a Windows bat file.

The idea is to have a small UI internally for our team so that a user can use a UI menu to select what to run, define parameters via forms, Compare the log, etc.

What would be the best and easiest way to do this?

1. Use PHP as UI
2. Use Perl CGI for web development
3. Java and JSP
4. Oracle Apex
5. Any other options (ASP, Ruby etc.)

Background knowledge

1. Database - Expert
2. Perl - Intermediate (not worked on CGI though)
3. Oops concepts - Expert
4. Java/.Net - Very Basic

Please suggest what would be the best approach given a limited time constraint the above knowledge.

Comment: if you run perl scripts in command line you could use [wxPerl](http://www.wxperl.it/) to create GUI (desktop apps).

Comment: How about a more recent perl web framework like [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/)

Answer (score 3):

Personally, what I've done in similar cases (as recently as earlier this week) is to convert the guts of the script to a small Perl module (which *should* be quick and easy if the script is well-structured), then use the [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/) web framework to create simple forms which collect the data and feed it to the module.

Dancer is quicker and easier to use (and to learn!) than plain CGI, plus this approach avoids the additional security issues introduced by having to interact with the shell to fire off a command-line script.